# Tableau packed bubbles - arrange the bubbles custom

Tags: visualization, tableau-desktop, bubble-chart

I'm looking to create a packed bubble graph like the below (size of the bubble corresponds to population, and the color of the bubble corresponds to number of widgets sales). The graph is exactly the way I need it, except that I would like to arrange the countries so that they are grouped by continent. Is there a way to do this in Tableau?

[image]

Comment: did the answer solve your need? if so, please consider accepting it in order to mark the question as canswered

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tried to recreate a similar scenario even though it's not clear if the bubble color should (or not) be related to a specific field.

That being said, using the superstore dataset, I've "grouped" customers by region (color) so they are some how aligned through inner circles.

In order to do so, I just sorted the region pillow in the detail section.

See below.

[image]